# How to Create a Web Form to Collect Data

Tags: html, database, webforms

Just to preface, I do have some programming experience at the basic level (HTML, CSS, Java, JavaScript, Python, VB.net, C++, C#) so I feel comfortable learning whatever I need to learn.

I am trying to create a web form to collect student information to be stored in a database/spreadsheet. I also want to be able to use information entered to send an e-mail to a reference (I am thinking drop-down list to select the recipient, but I might be a little ambitious with that). Then I want the reference to receiving a link to a web form that they would fill out and then that information would be connected back to the student.

For me, this is a huge project, but before I get started, I am looking for advice on what I need to learn. My default for making web pages is DreamWeaver (please don't criticize I am a novice) but am open to suggestions. Can anyone please advice me on what tools I will need to learn to complete this project? Can I use DreamWeaver? Can I use VB.net? Do I need PHP or some specific type of server setup (it's for a school, so the less I do on the server end, the better)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/). It may be basic, with simple fields and option selectors, but it has most of the capabilities you require. It is also extremely simple to set up.

It has dropdown menus for users to choose from emails.

You can link a [Google Sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en) to it, so all results are stored in a spreadsheet.